# how to get stdclass object value in php

Tags: php, stdclass

```
stdClass Object
(
[Transaction] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Reference1] => 001
        [Reference2] => 
        [Reference3] => 
        [Reference4] => 
        [Reference5] => 
    )

[Notifications] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[HasErrors] => 
[Shipments] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ProcessedShipment] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 3702106321
                [Reference1] => Shpt 0001
                [Reference2] => 
                [Reference3] => 
                [ForeignHAWB] => 
                [HasErrors] => 
                [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [ShipmentLabel] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [LabelURL] => http://www.sandbox.aramex.com/content/rpt_cache/cc1703518ef04f13873f8c2a2fab04fb.pdf
                        [LabelFileContents] => 
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

Can anyone help me how do I retrieve the value of ID?

Comment: For PHP Object you use `Object->Key`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$your_object->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->ID
```

where, `$your_object` contains your response, that you posted here.

Comment: Its not working. It generates an error "Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object"